# Dropdown submenus width issue in Chrome and IE

Tags: css

I am using a dropdown navigation menu in my drupal 7 site, on mouse over each parent item list down its sub menus correctly, but some of sub menus are of more width than others, for this reason i use `"width: -moz-max-content; position: relative;"` for firefox in css, so that all sub menus will have equal width to the one that has maximum content. This works perfectly in firfox only, but not in IE and chrome, please tell me if there is some alternate css property/method for IE and chrome to handle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious that `-moz-max-content` will work only in Firefox because it starts with `-moz`.

For Chrome you must use: `-webkit-max-content`
For Opera: `-o-max-content`
For IE (it should work): `max-content` or `-max-content` or `-ms-max-content` (I can't test it cause I use Linux)

Comment: A year and a half ago I posted elsewhere that this only worked in modern browsers and not IE9.

Comment: Thanks for replying djmati11.... can you please provide me some short example for IE and Chrome? i have tried the above just by replacing with the existing one, but it didn't worked:-(...

Comment: @Rob can you please provide me some alternate method/suggestions, which can solve this issue for all browsers together

Comment: @Prog_zd - There are no problems for all browsers. Only IE. That's always the case.

Comment: @Prog_zd just create line like this: `width: -moz-max-content; width: -webkit-max-content; width: -o-max-content; width: -ms-max-content;`